# Delete text after match in Ex?

Tags: normal-mode, ex-mode, ex-command

I've sample file like:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
```

and I'd like to remove everything till the matched line `dd`.

Normally in Vim I type: `d/dd` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it works.

When using in `ex`, it doesn't work as expected:

```
ex -s +"norm ggd/dd<cr>" +%p -cq! foo.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a better way of accomplishing the task you showed in ex mode, which is by using the `:delete` command and a basic `cmdline-range`.  To delete all lines between and including the beginning of the file and the search match, you can do this:

```
1,/dd/delete
```

If you don't want to include the matched line in the deletion, you can do this

```
1,/dd/-1delete
```

The first one works by selecting a range between the first line of the file and the first line that matches the pattern `dd`, which is then used by the delete command.  The second one is essentially the same, except there is a `-1` before `delete` which selects the line directly above the pattern `dd`.

For more on this, see `cmdline-ranges`.

Comment: What is the behavior of `ex` if the searched-for regex `/dd/` doesn't exist in the file?

Comment: @Wildcard the command simply doesn't do anything and the whole file is printed.